# Serializing Form Data Collection to Model using JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, json

Let's say I have an object like this:

```
public class Widget
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
}

public class Foo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And my controller method sends it to a View like this:

```
var widget = _dataAccess.GetWidget(someKey);
return View(widget);
```

And I have a View that looks like this:

```
@model MyNamespace.Widget

@using(Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Widgets", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "the-form" }))
{
    <p>@Html.TextBoxFor</p>

    @foreach(var foo in Model.Foos)
    {
        <p>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Foos.ToList()[Model.Foos.ToList().IndexOf(foo)])</p>   
    }

    <input type="button" value="Save Changes" id="the-button" />
}

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
        $("#the-button").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Edit", "Widgets")',
                type: 'POST',
                data: JSON.stringify({ widget: serializeForm("the-form") }),

                // etc, etc, not important
            });
        });
    });
    function serializeForm(formId) {
        var formData = {};
        $.each($("#" + formId).serializeArray(), function(){
            formData[this.name] = $(this).val();
        });
        return formData;
    }
</script>
```

Which serializes into:

```
{ "widget": { "Name" : "value from textbox", "[0].Name" : "some value", "[1].Name" : "some other value" } }
```

Of Course the serialization here isn't helpful because `[0].Name` isn't usable. Is there a way to change this so that it serializes to what the Post method controller action would expect? I.e., something like:

```
{ "widget":{"Name":"blah", "Foos":[ { "Name":"foo name 1"}, { "Name":"foo name 2"} ] }}
```

Comment: Does it have to be json or just something that will bind to Widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can output the Foos as:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.Foos.Count(); i++) {
    <input type="text" name="Foos[@i].Name" value="@Model.Foos.ElementAt(i).Name" />
}
```

You can then easily post the form:

```
 $("#the-button").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Edit", "Widgets")',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('this').closest('form').serialize(),

        // etc, etc, not important
    });
});
```

Phil Haack's [post](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) on model binding a list explains this in depth.

Comment: I did figure this out eventually from a Phil haack post on this topic. Doesn't make your answer any less correct though, thank you kindly!

Comment: That's a great reference.  I've added a link to it in the answer.